# How can I change the buttons order of the main toolbar inside eclipse 4 application?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

Hey I have a normal toolbar inside the Application.e4xmi,  which gets his elements from several other fragment.e4xmi / plugins. How can I change the order of these?

Current toolbar:

[image: Current toolbar]

and how I want it:

[image: Wanted one]

The Plugins are here seperated by the spotted lines.

The whole thing is handeld by .e4xmi files and theire handler classes and each plugin has an toolbar with the main toolbar as parent.

Thanks for help :D

Comment: You can use "Position in list" in the model fragment definition - see [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#position-of-new-model-elements)

Comment: You can also use a "model processor" defined in the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.model` extension point to rearrange to toolbar

Comment: Thanks, first advice worked. Saw this already but with other id`s and this didnt worked. With id:number its working :D